# load 32 bits from memory into xmm register

Tags: sse, inline-assembly, intrinsics, sse2, mmx

inline assembly:

```
__asm__("movd (%0), %%xmm1" : : "r"(some_pointer) :);
```

What is the equivalent intrinsics code?

```
__m128i foo = _mm_?????(some_pointer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int32_t *foo_pointer;

__m128i foo = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(*foo_pointer); // MOVD
```

For future reference see the handy [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Given you want it into an integer SSE register, you're probably looking for [_mm_cvtsi32_si128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct3539ha%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).